# How to load an Image direcly to a page with PHP?

Tags: php, html, image

I have an image in a directiory, lets say: `test.jpg`.

I also have 2 other PHP file in this directory called: `new.php` and `load.php`

Now, what I want to do is, when people visit the website `new.php`, they should need to see the `test.jpg` image.

However! I would also need that if I place the `new.php` into an `<img>` tag, it should also display the image correctly.

I have tried to call the image in an `img` tag, but it doesn't load correctly, when I insert the `new.php` into `img` tags.

```
<img src="test.jpg">
```

How is that even possible to make a php work as an image - if you know what I mean?

Comment: please give sample code about what you mean..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('path/to/image/screenshot.jpg');
```

other variants:

```
@readfile('path/to/image/screenshot.jpg');
```

won't have any errors if file does not exist.

AND

```
readfile('path/to/image/screenshot.jpg') or die('Image file not found');
```

will kill your script with a predefined error message if file does not exist.

The most useful alternative, as suggested by @hd:

```
$file = 'path/to/image/screenshot.jpg';
readfile(file_exists($file) ? $file : 'path/to/image/image_not_found.jpg');
```

Which will choose `$file` or if it does not exist, the default `image_not_found.jpg`

You may need to change the mime-type in the `header()` for other image types.

Note: The other answer is very much as functional as this one, but this one uses no memory and in general is faster and more flexible than the other answer.

Comment: I'd also check that the file actually exists, before reading it. You know, for those rare occasions.

Comment: Thank you this is working very well. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @hd, as much as I hate them; in this case `@readfile();` would be simplest.

Comment: Ew. Suppressing errors on production is a big no-no, in my books. A simple `file_exists` should suffice!

Comment: Without testing, wouldn't the second alternate work?

Comment: It would, but you could check if the file exists first, and if it doesn't display a "Image not found" image, rather than destroying the user experience with a dead image.

Comment: you could die an Image not found image, while it really wouldn't look nice on the backend, having the raw bytes in the string.

Comment: I was thinking of `$imagePath = file_exists('path/to/image/screenshot.jpg') ? 'path/to/image/screenshot.jpg' : 'path/to/image/image_not_found.jpg';`. This way it will render an image, and not show the [broken image link](http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_broken_image_00_a_logo.gif)

Comment: For the sake of argument I will add a ternary statement into one of the alts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**new.php**

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("test.jpg");

imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

and use it like this

```
<img src="new.php"/>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg())` would be more CPU costly then a simple `readfile()`

Comment: Yes. But it's one way of doing it :)

Comment: +1'ing because it's an alternative to @t3chguy's approach. To make it valid HTML, add `/>` at the end of the `img` tag - closing the tag properly.